# DataTable - TableTools ShowSelectedOnly

Tags: javascript, datatables, tabletools

I'm trying to use the DataTable plugin for TableTools.ShowSelectedOnly, but I have difficulties to make it works.
Relative plugin page : [TableTools.ShowSelectedOnly](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/TableTools.ShowSelectedOnly)

I use *Example* given in the plugin documentation :
- for the selection : it works good.

But I don't see button for `Show all` or `Show Selected` ?

Actually, I don't understand where the box contained `oFilterSelectedOptions` appears ?
(describe as *"select box to show all or only selected items"* in the plugin)

I probably missed some basic instruction... but I'm neewbie on javascript.

Did some one could help me ?
Here is my test code : http://jsfiddle.net/K5g9q/

Answer (score 3):

Finnaly I found solution !

There is a little mistake in the example , you should use the `sDom` option `O`.
So, the good example is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">OSrtip', 
         "oTableTools": { 
             "sRowSelect": "multi", 
         },
         "oLanguage": { 
         "oFilterSelectedOptions": { 
              AllText: "All Row", 
              SelectedText: "Selected Row" 
              } 
         } 
    }); 
});
```

Then adjust the dom positionning if you want.
Edit of jsfiddle with working example : http://jsfiddle.net/K5g9q/3/

Hope it helps.